# Ищу online курсы по Java

Tags: java

Посоветуйте. пожалуйста хорошие online курсы по Java, котррые выдают сертификат об окончании.
Имею уже оыт программирования на PYTHON.

Заранее спасибо,

Дмитрий

Comment: Посмотрите online курсы на платформах coursera и udemy. На udemy есть сортировка по рейтингу, можете почитать комментарии о курсе и что получаете после его прохождения. Coursera строже, там курсы под определенный график построены, но в конце гарантируют сертификаты.

Comment: УЦ "Специалист" выдает сертификат об окончании.

Comment: Почитайте книгу Шилдта Java 8 для профессионалов

Comment: Ни один сертификат не будет котироваться лучше IMHO, чем нативный сертификат от oracle - Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 8 Programmer. а подготовка к нему хорошая у http://enthuware.com/index.php/mock-exams/oracle-certified-associate/java-oca-certification-8